# BroadcastReceiver is working only if app is active

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I trying to implement sending notifications at specific time even if the app is not active
but it only works if the app is active (opened)

in onCreate

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000)), broadcast);
```

the receiver Class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent it = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
        createNotification(context, it, "new mensage", "body!", "this is a mensage");

    }

    public void createNotification(Context context, Intent intent, CharSequence ticker, CharSequence title, CharSequence descricao) {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setTicker(ticker);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(descricao);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        builder.setContentIntent(p);
        Notification n = builder.build();
        //create the notification
        n.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 400};
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify(R.drawable.icon, n);
        //create a vibration
        try {

            Uri som = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone toque = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, som);
            toque.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

the androidmanifest:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.atefhares.study_organizer.notifications_related.AlarmReceiver"
                android:enabled="true">
          <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Any one knows how to solve this, Please ??

Comment: where is your variable alarm defined?

Comment: above the usage line

Comment: if it's at activity level once your activity is removed from memory same happens to AlarmManager

Comment: so is there any solution to make it work if activity is not in memory ?